# IS it possible to create Sharepoint 2013 document set using Rest api from provider hosted app?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a Provide hosted app. I want to create a Document Set in Sharepoint Site collection if not available and add some documents . is it possible to do So using a rest api call.

Comment: Yes. Did you google? This is the exact same question: 
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114882/is-it-possible-to-create-a-document-set-using-rest-api

Comment: Yes but they are using the listdata.svc in the end and where the slug is the key to create ..
i want to achieve using complete API call as i will calling this from the Provide hosted app webapp where cross domain will come in picture